# Disable VsCode autocompletion in Typescript files when hitting type closing bracket '>'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I use vscode and love auto-completion. But vscode keeps trying to auto-complete when I hit the `>` character. So when I type  `type A<R>`, it will suggest `ReadonlyArray` and write `type A<ReadonlyArray` as soon as I hit the `>` character. I have to type `Ctrl+Z` to cancel the auto-completion and retype the `>` character. I feel this is linked to what vscode calls trigger characters but so far my attempts at suppressing > as a trigger character have all failed. Would someone have a solution to this? I think I only need Enter as a trigger character. Here is what my configuration looks like as far as hinting is concerned:

```json
// Hinting
  "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
  },
  "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false, // No completion after typing dot
  "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on",
  "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,
  "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
  "editor.tabCompletion": "off",
  "editor.suggest.localityBonus": true,
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": "matchingDocuments",
  "editor.parameterHints.enabled": true,
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "choseToUpdateConfiguration",
```

Here is the contents that shows on calling `Help:About`:

```
Version: 1.86.2
Commit: 903b1e9d8990623e3d7da1df3d33db3e42d80eda
Date: 2024-02-13T19:40:56.878Z
Electron: 27.2.3
ElectronBuildId: 26908389
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

Comment: weird. I can't reproduce this. Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.

Comment: Hi, added the contents of 'Help:About' command

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the Inline HTML extension was responsible for this mess! Just in case somebody else has the same issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).